# NetBeans The module has not been deployed Error

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, tomcat7, netbeans6.8

I have created a app using `NetBeans 6.8` and `Tomcat 7`. When i'm trying to run my application, i'm getting error as `The module has not been deployed` from below line in `build-impl.xml`.

```
<target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
     // error come from below line
    <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
</target>
```

How can i solve this ?

Comment: hey bishan, did you find a solution for this problem? I've got the same error and can't find anything on the net about how to fix this.

Comment: @safari Unfortunately **no**. :(

Comment: hmm, I've found a solution for at least deploying your app on glassfish manually, check my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976377/deployment-error-java-webproject-from-netbeans-to-glassfish-4-0

Comment: Great :) i have moved eclipse and make my project.

Comment: please refer here


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573787/apache-tomcat-7-0-14build-impl-xml1111-the-module-has-not-been-deployed/22777586#22777586


I have shared my experience

Answer (score -1):

(1) To sure check it first:

MY JDK 1.8(default).
my tomcat 8.0.3.0

(2) Then you should write coding of your application correctly.

(3) if problem occur " Module has not been deployed ".

(4) you should disconnect your network connection.

(5) than restart the computer.

(6) run the project again.

Answer (score -1):

It maybe because you may need to create `Db Resource` and `Pool` manually on the Glassfish server like this,

In `Netbeans -> Projects, Open Server Resources -> glassfish-resources.xml`
We have to create JDBC Resource and JDBC Connection Pool Manually on Glassfish. I am using my values here, don't use them, see your .xml !

Value of `jndi-name` is your JDBC Resource and Value of `pool-name` is your JDBC Connection Pool.

Open Browser for Glassfish Admin,
https://localhost:4848/

Go to `JDBC Connection Pool -> New:`
1) Pool Name: `mysql_customersdb_rootPool`
2) Resource Type: `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource`
3) Database Driver Vendor: `MySql`

Press `Next`

`URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customersdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`
`Url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customersdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`
`User: root`
`Password: root`

`JDBC Resources -> New`

`JNDI Name: CustomersDS`
`Pool Name: mysql_customersdb_rootPool`

Press Ok.

Right Click your Project and Press Run :)