# Deployment-Error: Java-Webproject from netbeans to glassfish 4.0

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, web-deployment, glassfish-4

**Setup**

---

I'm using `Netbeans 7.4` on Mac OSX Mavericks and `Glassfish 4.0 (build 89)` on my dedicated server and `JDK 1.7`. To use the server locally I setup and ssh-tunnel. The following way:

```
ssh -L 4848:127.0.0.1:4848 -p 6122 glassfish@XXXXXXXXXX
```

This is working perfectly fine, I can access the server via localhost without any problems. To use this server I added a server in Netbeans, see prinscreen:

[image: Serversetup in Netbeans]

**Problem**

---

Now I'd like to deploy the project to the server (Right-Click Project -> Deploy) but I get following Error:

```
Building jar: /Users/tzhware7/NetBeansProjects/SkyLogicAddon/dist/SkyLogicAddon.war
Distributing /Users/tzhware7/NetBeansProjects/SkyLogicAddon/dist/SkyLogicAddon.war to [glassfish.ivo]
glassfish.ivo, deploy, null, false
/Users/tzhware7/NetBeansProjects/SkyLogicAddon/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1050: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Now I'd checked the line where the Error-Show's up, which is following (1049-1051). For me everything looks normal:

```
<target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
        <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
    </target>
```

In advance I checked the serverlogs, which are empty - no error is shown. What am I doing wrong? Can someone advice me what to change? Thank you in advance!

**Edit 1 - 08.01.2014**

---

Allright, *I didn't found a solution for solving the problem above*, but following way worked at least to deploy the app manually.

1. Netbeans -> Right-Click on Project -> Clean/Build (now check your outputlog where it save's the project.
2. Now go to that path, you'll shoud find a `.war` file
3. Log into your glassfish-server -> Click Application's -> Click deploy -> upload the `.war` file -> Click again deploy

Now glassfish deploys the project for you. :)

**Edit 2 - 17.01.2014**

---

I could fix the problem, following was wrong. In netbeans I configured that the Target should be domain1, if you do this, it won't work. Let the target be empty, and everything works fine.

*Thank you Tim B for your help!*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If NetBeans can't talk to the server when you add it to the list then it silently fails. The server appears in the list but you can't click on the + and expand it out to see what it contains.

Check in your server list that NetBeans can actually see the server. Also keep in mind that NetBeans needs access to the admin port (usually 4848) not the normal web one, although it looks like your tunnel is correct for that.

You also need to turn on remote administration and set up the username and password etc. Try pointing a web browser to your localhost 6122 and check you can log in to the admin panel using the same username and password that netbeans is using.

To turn on remote administration:

https://blogs.oracle.com/quinn/entry/securing_adminstration_in_glassfish_server1

```
asadmin enable-secure-admin
```

You will also need to add an administrator username and password.

Comment: where to turn on remote administration?

Comment: thank you, but secure admin is allready enabled and username and password are set... :(

Comment: Are you able to connect to the admin page using a web browser with the same settings as netbeans has? Keep in mind that netbeans has its own proxy/network settings as well. In the Services view can you expand the glassfish.ivo entry and see the applications, resources, etc inside?

Comment: yes I can connect using a webbrowser with the same settings as netbeans has. If check it in netbeans, the server seems to be empty but, i can restart it from netbeans, and see that the server is running...

Comment: ah I just found out what was wrong - in Target I put domain1 - I deleted this now, everything works fine....