# Apache Tomcat 7.0.14:build-impl.xml:1111: The module has not been deployed

Tags: java, netbeans, tomcat7, netbeans-7, meta-inf

While deploying a project in *Netbeans7.4* It is not deploying project in *Apache Tomcat 7.0.14* am it is showing following

```
E:\Project\atom\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1111: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 22 seconds)
```

line no:1111 at `built-impl.xml` is

```
<nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" 
forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

To resolve above problem I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16575263/876739)

My `context.xml` file contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/atom"/>
```

And all permission is set for general users

How to resolve this problem, what can be other cause for this error

**Edit**: Now installed *Netbeans 8.0* and *Apache Tomcat 8* then also showing same problem
          I am using `struts2.3.15` and `hibernet3.6`

My `web.xml` content is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class> business.schedular.QuartzSchedulerListener </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            120
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>pages/login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: May be the best would be to see into server logs if possible. Check the tomcat Apache Tomcat 7.0.14 where it's available on your machine. Browses to it, then to logs and see if it's generating logs containing the original error for which application failed to deploy.

Comment: Also I've never tried it, but may be change the line in built-impl.xml to say debugmode="true". May be you'll see more verbose error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing this issue often,and let me share my experience:

> when I experience this issue, I just switch off my wireless network
>   connectivity and then I will restart Netbeans 7.4 in the wireless
>   offline mode. Once it is restarted I will deploy all the applications
>   which I have to execute for a day.

Deployment will be done Successfully. Later you can activate wireless/network connectivity in your system,further deployment doesn't shows the error.

Until closing Neatbeans7.4, you can deploy,you can clean and build, you can do whatever you want.

But if you are planning to restart the IDE again, Do the same, Deactivate the wireless/network connectivity and do the deployment.

I am handling this issue daily by following the above steps.

> Before Wireless/Network Activation:

[image]

> After Wireless/Network Activation:

[image]

Comment: Yes after deactivating wireless it is successful deploying but on browser it is showing 404 please see this link https://imgur.com/a/LsFli

Comment: It seems the error is in your struts action configuration file(struts.xml). You have created an action in jsp but haven't mapped any class and method to perform that action in java. So please check it.

Comment: @xrcwrn "Module has not been deployed",for this issue, the above is the solution, if you feel the same, mark it as right answer :)

Comment: According to my situation this was my problem. Later 404 error was due to jsp page path problem now every thing has resolved. thanks alot

Comment: This solution is not targeting the real problem. isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the web.xml file; all defined servlets in web.xml file should be in source. There may be some servlet definitions left behind after you delete or renamed servlet class files. If this is the case, netbeans still clean-build application successfully but cannot deploy.

Comment: see my `web.xml` contents

Comment: This error occurs when any class is not found in project. Check that "business.schedular.QuartzSchedulerListener" class is included in your project and also struts2 is there.

Comment: I am not sure if it matters but there are spaces before and after " business.schedular.QuartzSchedulerListener ".

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check your **XML** files are valid or not.

**Step1** If you are using NetBeans IDE just right click on XML file in your project and select **validate**

**Step2** If xml files don't have any error the open your project location and delete the **build.xml** file and redeploy the application again.

It may be helpful to you. All the best

Answer (score 0):

Where is the location of your project.If it is in C drive , this kind of problem may arise.Because , clean and build process requires some of the file modification.But , the c drive will not grant it.Just try the same after changing the location of project.

Answer (score 0):

I faced above problem because I was using proxy server.
Due to proxy server It is showing the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem go to C:\Users\yourComputerName\AppData\Local\NetBeans
 and delete the cache folder.This definately solved my problem.

Comment: After following this step I've re-installed my Netbeans.

Comment: After following your solution my Netbeans stopped working. So, re-installed it.

Comment: you just had to restart the Netbeans